# Two similar GANs, one of them fail, while the other one works perfectly fine. What is the problem in the failing one?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, generative-adversarial-network

One of the codes I took from a site just returns a noise to me, while the other one is working perfectly fine. I tried to make them very similar (one of them was in functions, while the other one wasnt, so I took them out of functions for example) and now, the only difference is that one of them is randomly selecting the batch using a numpy random, while the other one is using tensorflow to get batches (?) I believe.

Can someone explain to me why the numpy one doesnt work? In the end, they should be accomplishing similar things. Why isnt this the case?

Here's the working code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2DTranspose, Conv2D, BatchNormalization, Reshape, LeakyReLU, Flatten, Dropout
from IPython import display

(x_train, _), (_,_) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.0

batch_size = 128
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_train).shuffle(1000)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True).prefetch(1)

generator = Sequential()

generator.add(Dense(7*7*128, input_dim=100))
generator.add(Reshape((7,7,128)))
generator.add(BatchNormalization())
generator.add(Conv2DTranspose(64, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='same', activation='selu'))
generator.add(BatchNormalization())
generator.add(Conv2DTranspose(1, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='same', activation='tanh'))

discriminator = Sequential()

discriminator.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='same', input_shape=(28,28,1)))
discriminator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
discriminator.add(Dropout(0.3))
discriminator.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='same'))
discriminator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
discriminator.add(Dropout(0.3))
discriminator.add(Flatten())
discriminator.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')
discriminator.trainable = False
gan = Sequential([generator, discriminator])
gan.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')
def train(gan, dataset, batch_size, epochs=5):
    gen, disc = gan.layers
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        print('epoch:{0}/{1}'.format(epoch+1, epochs))
        for x_batch in dataset:
            # noise = tf.random.normal(shape=[batch_size, 100])
            noise = np.random.normal(0,1,size=(batch_size, 100))
            gen_img = generator(noise)
            x_fake_and_real = tf.concat([gen_img, tf.reshape(x_batch, (128,28,28,1))], axis=0)
            y1 = np.zeros(2*batch_size)
            y1[batch_size:] = 1
            discriminator.trainable = True
            discriminator.train_on_batch(x_fake_and_real, y1)
            noise = np.random.normal(0,1,size=(batch_size, 100))
            y2 = np.ones(batch_size)
            discriminator.trainable = False
            gan.train_on_batch(noise, y2)
    noise = np.random.normal(0,1,size=(1, 100))
    pred = generator.predict(noise)
    plt.imshow(pred.reshape(28,28))
train(gan, dataset, 128)

#This is the test:
noise = np.random.normal(0,1,size=(1, 100))
pred = generator.predict(noise)
plt.imshow(pred.reshape(28,28), cmap='gray')
```

outputs [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLUQu.png)

Here's the code that refuses to work and returns a noisy image back:

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2DTranspose, Conv2D, BatchNormalization, Reshape, LeakyReLU, Flatten, Dropout
(x_train, _), (_,_) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255
x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 28,28,1)

generator = Sequential()

generator.add(Dense(7*7*128, input_dim=100))
generator.add(Reshape((7,7,128)))
generator.add(BatchNormalization())
generator.add(Conv2DTranspose(64, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='same', activation='selu'))
generator.add(BatchNormalization())
generator.add(Conv2DTranspose(1, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='same', activation='tanh'))


discriminator = Sequential()

discriminator.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='same', input_shape=(28,28,1)))
discriminator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
discriminator.add(Dropout(0.3))
discriminator.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='same'))
discriminator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
discriminator.add(Dropout(0.3))
discriminator.add(Flatten())
discriminator.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

discriminator.trainable = False
gan = Sequential([generator, discriminator])
discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')
gan.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')
dLosses = []
gLosses = []

def train(gan, epochs=10, batch_size=128):
    generator, discriminator = gan.layers
    batch_count = int(x_train.shape[0] / batch_size)
    print('Epochs: ', epochs)
    print('Batch Size: ', batch_size)
    print('Batch Count: ', batch_count)
    for epoch in range(1,epochs+1):
        print('-'*15, 'Epoch: {0}'.format(epoch), '-'*15)
        for _ in range(batch_count):
            noise = np.random.normal(0,1, size=[batch_size, 100])
            img_batch = x_train[np.random.randint(0, x_train.shape[0], size=batch_size)]
            
            gen_img = generator.predict(noise)
            X = np.concatenate([gen_img, img_batch])
            dis_y = np.zeros(2*batch_size)
            dis_y[batch_size:] = 1
            
            discriminator.trainable = True
            dloss = discriminator.train_on_batch(X, dis_y)
            #new batch
            noise = np.random.normal(0,1, size=(batch_size, 100))
            yGen = np.ones(batch_size)
            discriminator.trainable = False
            gloss = gan.train_on_batch(noise, yGen)
            dLosses.append(dloss)
            gLosses.append(gloss)    

train(gan)

#Test code:
noise = np.random.normal(0,1,size=(1, 100))
pred = generator(noise)
plt.imshow(pred.reshape(28,28), cmap='gray')
```

outputs [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jkbwa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still dont know why one of them worked and the other didnt. But, I finally built a GAN that works consistently using TF2.0. It's using the WGAN-GP architecture. Even though there were a lot of code examples of this architecture for PyTorch, I couldnt find anything for Keras, and most of them were outdated (coded in TF1.0).

So I built it myself! Here's the [link](https://github.com/mehmetcanakbay/wgan-gp-tensorflow2.0/) to my github. I know this is not a direct answer to my question, but from what I've researched, WGAN-GP is just a better way to make a GAN overall instead of DCGAN. It also didnt feel right to just abandon the question even though I found an answer, even if its indirect.

Anyways, good luck to everyone :)